# Error parsing double in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, parsing, double

I created an android application that interacts with web service.

I obtain the following error:

```
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{aid.assistant233/aid.assistant233.AidAssistant233Activity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:267)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:318)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at aid.assistant233.AidAssistant233Activity.SaveMapsToLocalDB(AidAssistant233Activity.java:1149)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at aid.assistant233.AidAssistant233Activity.UpdateApplicationData(AidAssistant233Activity.java:1060)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at aid.assistant233.AidAssistant233Activity.UpdateFromServer(AidAssistant233Activity.java:480)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at aid.assistant233.AidAssistant233Activity.onCreate(AidAssistant233Activity.java:212)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
01-29 1
```

0:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):   ... 11 more

The main problem I think is related to:

```
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:267)
01-29 10:50:09.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:318)
```

The associated code is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dati.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element element = (Element) dati.item(i);
                    localDB.insertMap(XmlElemValue(element, "Title"), Double.parseDouble(XmlElemValue(element, "Latitude")),  // line 1149
                            Double.parseDouble(XmlElemValue(element, "Longitude")), Integer.parseInt(XmlElemValue(element, "MetriDistanza")),
                            Integer.parseInt(XmlElemValue(element, "MinutiIntervalloControllo")));
                }
```

The tag latitude in the xml returned by the webservice is:

```
<Latitude>43.5729</Latitude>
```

Comment: can you check the value coming inside parseDouble() and parseInt() methods?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on line 1149.  Run your app.  What value does XmlElemValue(element, "Latitude") return?

Comment: Check your locale specific settings, maybe the it expects `43,5729` instead of `43.5729`.

Comment: But this code somethings works good. The data returned from web service are always the same.

Comment: Please tell us what value is returned. It might be the same as the tag you've shown us, it might not.  Only then can we help.  Several people have asked for this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your associated code at the invocation

```
Double.parseDouble(XmlElemValue(element, "Latitude"))
```

`A NumberFormatException` is thrown, if the string does not contain a parsable double.

**You have to check the value before passing it to `parseDouble`**. Maybe the latitude value is provded in the Degree Minutes Seconds (DMS) format.

Answer (score 0):

In `Line 1149` are you sure `(XmlElemValue(element, "Latitude")` is a string value which holds `integer/double`. The Problem is your parsing the value which is not a integer/double value. Thats why you getting `Number Format Exception`. Check that line by printing out.

Answer (score 0):

Your locale is probably set so that Java is expecting a decimal comma instead of a decimal point.
Try this:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
Double doubleValue = nf.parse(XmlElemValue(element, "Latitude")).doubleValue();
```